# crone job, send email with attachment php script

Tags: php, email, attachment

i need someone to prepare for me a crone job.

I have a link with xml data, and i need to send me a email with converted xml to csv every day at 3:00 am. Email with some text and attachment. There is someone which would help me on private message. Please :))

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we're not an outsourcing service

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=xml+to+csv&type=Repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, there's no private messaging help in computer coder's lands, as far as i know..

second, and to answer your question : you'll need to access either PHP or Python from cron, in order to convert the xml to a cvs file.

for that, you'll need to 'parse' whatever xml you're fed each day, into that cvs file.

good luck.